# How do I update cached data using updateQueryData (rtkQuery

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I'm new to rtkQuery, I am trying to do a simple update to my cached data, but I am failing drastically, I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if what I want to do is achievable.

Essentially I am querying data from an endpoint (that works), but I can't seem to update the cached data.

My code looks like this

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const usersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'usersApi',

    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2'}),

    endpoints: builder => ({
        getUsers: builder.query({
            query: () => '/users?pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow',
        })
    })
})

export const updateUser = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch(usersApi.util.updateQueryData("getUsers", undefined, (users) => {
    return {
      ...users,
      user
    }
  }))
}

export const { useGetUsersQuery } = usersApi
```

And this is how I am trying to use the `updateUser`

```
  const FollowUser = (user) => {
    let followers =  user.followers || 0
    followers++
    const userWithFollowers = { ...user, followers }

     updateUser(dispatch, userWithFollowers)
  }
```

Is this something that can be achieved using rtkQuery ? or am I not understanding the usecase of `updateQueryData` ?

Comment: did you add the api middleware when configuring your store like in this [example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#configure-the-store) `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(usersApi.middleware),` ?

Comment: Hey @OlivierBoissé, Yea I've added the middleware

```middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(usersApi.middleware)```

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#example-1) it should be `users.push(user)` instead of `{...users, user}`

Comment: That could be the case, might need to format the data when I get it from the server because it returns an object instead of an array.

Comment: there is an [example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#example-2) manipulating an object. Simply do `users.user = user`

Comment: But I doubt it would know which user to update if I had to do ```users.user = user```

Comment: Just logged current(users) and I can confirm I got data 
```has_more: true
items: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
quota_max: 300
quota_remaining: 181```

Comment: so `users.items.push(user)` should be more appropriated